# POST method is not working with Request header

Tags: youtube, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

I want to send data to youtube by POST method. I write **http.open("POST", myUrl, true);** in the code as following

```
var myUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken";
 http.open("POST", myUrl, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "AuthSub token=" + code);
            http.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", 2);
            http.setRequestHeader("X-GData-Key", "key="+dev_key);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

but the error is

```
Request URL:https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

Kindly tell me what is the wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX doesn't allow you to send request to domains other than that which hosts the code?

Comment: I'm pretty novice at web programming BUT one option is to use JavaScript and JSON objects. Look into it a little bit, see if you can do it that way. If you can't or get stuck... StackOverflow isn't going anywhere...